# Send Thunderbird email with python

Tags: python, email, thunderbird

I'm trying to send emails from Python through my default browser (thunderbird).

This is what I've got.

```
from urllib import quote
import webbrowser

def mailto(recipients, subject, body):
    "recipients: string with comma-separated emails (no spaces!)"
    webbrowser.open("mailto:%s?subject=%s&body=%s" %
        (recipients, quote(subject), quote(body)))

body_template = """Hello %(name)s!

How are you?"""

def gen(email, name):
    mailto(email, "Hi!", body_template % locals())

gen("joe@example.com", "Joe")
gen("jane@example.com,jill@example.com", "Jane and Jill")
```

This code executes with no errors, it creates the email correctly but it actually doesn't send it. The output of the script is a thunderbird email waiting for someone to press "send" to be sent.
How to I automate the last piece?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to send the emails specifically from the thunderbird desktop app rather than entirely programatically from python?

Comment: Without having done a ton of research, it seemed the fastest way to send an email without having to explicitly have my password in the script.

Comment: I don't know that it's possible. If it is it would have the advantage of using Tbird to keep copies of these messages with all others.

Comment: Maybe a different route? https://superuser.com/questions/406580/writing-scripts-that-work-with-my-emails